# Создать поток с таймером отдельным потоком java android

Tags: java, android, многопоточность, таймер

Хочу создать таймер отдельным от программы потоком. Необходимо, чтобы он выводился на экран вместе с основной программой. Создал динамический layout, динамический TextView, создал поток, и сделал таймер. программа вылетает как только я нажимаю на кнопку. В чем ошибка? можно ли как-то это сделать по-другому. (Необходимо просто чтобы человек видел время сколько осталось до конца теста, дается 20 минут). Прошу прощения за говнокод, на java прогаю второй день.

```
 public void addListenerOnButton () {
btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.to_test_one);
btn.setOnClickListener(
        new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                ((ViewGroup) btn.getParent()).removeView(btn);
                rand();
                Thread th = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run(){
                        new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {

                            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                                timeLayout = (LinearLayout)  findViewById(R.id.mainLinearTimer);
                                TimTxt.setText(tim);
                                timeLayout.addView(TimTxt);
                                tim--;
                            }

                            public void onFinish() {
                                TimTxt.setText("Конец");
                                timeLayout.addView(TimTxt);
                            }
                        }.start();
                    }
                });
                th.start(); 
                paint();
            }
        }
);
```

}

Comment: Не нужно делать таймер в отдельном потоке, а `TextView` надо сделать глобальной переменной и обновлять ее на onTick()

Comment: Убрал поток, сделал `TextView TimTxt;` и так же вылетает

Comment: Добавьте вопрос стектрейс ошибки, найдите и укажите строчку, в которой она происходит

Comment: без стектрейса проблема неявна, но вот timeLayout получать при каждом тике  - явно неправильно.

Comment: Какая именно ошибка?